# Does getadapteraddresses function support mediasense function by default?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am trying to use the getadapteraddresses function to display all the adapter addresses  both IPv4 and IPv6. 
My goal is to ensure that only the adapters with the active link status should be displayed in the AdapterDialogScreen. However, as of now all the adapter addresses are displayed if they are just enabled, though there is no cabled connected to the adapter/wireless not connected.
How do I restrict the display of the adapter information based on the link status.

Answer (score 0):

You could check 'OperStatus' member of [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is returned by getadapteraddresses.
Value 'IfOperStatusUp' means 'The interface is up and able to pass packets'.